# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array, sometime works, sometime does not

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, parsing

MainTVC shows pictures and title of post in tableView by retrieving PFObjects from parse.com, if I tap one of the tableView Cell, it will show detail post view that contains pictures and texts. mainTVC pass data to detailView by using prepareForSegue.

Most of time, it is working well, but when I try tap it right after tableView shows picture or I scroll really fast,  I get an error, especially when I do it with slow internet.

> 2015-10-22 14:36:52.501 bany[2595:874380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array’
>
> 2015-10-22 14:39:40.855 bany[2600:875293] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'

sometime I get  index 2 beyond bounds for empty array, sometime zero.

I don't think that I have an empty indexPath.

I guess, I tap on it before retrieving data has been done.

here is my MainTVC Code

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MainTVC: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var categorySegment: UISegmentedControl!

var resultSearchController : UISearchController!



lazy var postsArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
lazy var filterdArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var objectArray = [String]()
  var parentObjectID = String()

var objectTwo : PFObject!
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

        //사이즈 조절

        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    bringAllDatafromParse()
}


@IBAction func segmentTapped(sender: AnyObject) {




    postsArray = []



    switch categorySegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0 :
        bringAllDatafromParse()
    case 1 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(1)

    case 2 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(2)

    case 3 :
        bringCategoryDataFromParse(3)

    default :
        bringAllDatafromParse()



    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return postsArray.count


}





    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTVCE





       var postObjects = self.postsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject




    cell.didRequestToShowComment = { (cell) in
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let objectToSend = self.postsArray[indexPath!.row] as? PFObject
        // Show your Comment view controller here, and set object to send here
        self.objectTwo = objectToSend!
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainToComment", sender: self)


    }
    cell.soldLabel.hidden = true

    if (postObjects.objectForKey("sold") as! Bool) == true {
        cell.soldLabel.hidden = false

    }

            //제목

    cell.titleLabel.text = postObjects.objectForKey("titleText") as! String

            // 닉네임

    if let nickNameExists = postObjects.objectForKey("nickName") as? String {
        cell.nickNameLabel.text = nickNameExists
    }else {
        cell.nickNameLabel.text = postObjects.objectForKey("username") as? String
    }



    //시간
    let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM /dd /yy"
    cell.timeLabel.text = (dateFormatter.stringFromDate(postObjects.createdAt!))



            // 가격

    let price = (postObjects.objectForKey("priceText") as! String)
            cell.priceLable.text = "   $\(price)"



               // 이미지
    let mainImages = postObjects.objectForKey("front_image") as! PFFile


    mainImages.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        cell.mainPhoto.image = image
    }

    // 프로필
    if let profileImages = (postObjects.objectForKey("profile_picture") as? PFFile){
                profileImages.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    cell.profilePhoto.image = image

        }

    }else{ cell.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "AvatarPlaceholder")
    }
    circularImage(cell.profilePhoto)

    return cell
}


    // MARK: - Animate Table View Cell

//    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell                cell:   UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//        cell.alpha = 0
        //        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        //          //            cell.alpha = 1
//        }
//    }
//


func bringAllDatafromParse() {
    //activityIndicatorOn()

    postsArray = []
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")

    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil{

            for object : PFObject in objects! {

                self.postsArray.addObject(object)

            }

            let array : Array = self.postsArray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects


            self.postsArray = array as! NSMutableArray


        }
     self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

}





func bringCategoryDataFromParse(category : Int) {



    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
     query.whereKey("category", equalTo: category)
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && objects != nil{

            for object : PFObject in objects! {

                self.postsArray.addObject(object)

            }

            let array : Array = self.postsArray.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects


            self.postsArray = array as! NSMutableArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


    }

}




 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

 if (segue.identifier == "mainToComment") {


let destViewController : CommentVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CommentVC

let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

destViewController.object = objectTwo


}

if (segue.identifier == "mainToDetail") {


    let selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let destViewController : DetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailVC
            destViewController.object = (postsArray[(selectedRowIndex?.row)!] as? PFObject)


}

}

func circularImage(image : UIImageView) {
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
    image.clipsToBounds  = true
    image.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
}

}
```

**My question is**

If my guess is right, what should I do with my code for wait that retrieving data from parse?

If it is not, what is the reason of this error? and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to provide more code and details but two things come to mind.

First, according to the name of the function, it appears you're adding things to the array in another background queue while trying to represent or interact with them on the main queue via the UI (your table view). I'm not sure how Parse works but at a glance, I'd make sure you don't have multiple background query instances playing with your array at the same time.

Second, it's unclear to me how you're handling cell reuse. Could your cells be trying to make use of information from a previous time they were used to represent another row, before being reused? Maybe you're not fully resetting all state.

**Update for Questions in Comments**

Looking into Parse (which I've never used), I see that you're not quite using it properly. [This example](https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery) shows (in Objective-C) how your call to `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(...)` should be handled. The example doesn't appear to demonstrate how to handle updating your UI.

The contents of the block is being run in the background. Google "cocoa UI thread safety" and read as much as you can. It applies to more general thread safety issues as well. I think every time your UI is creating table cells or interacting with them, the array holds something different (which would affect count). You're also doing a lot of replacing of your `postsArray` in the background and all of this will "trip up" your table view, since UI objects generally cannot be updated or manipulated from any but the main queue/thread.

What appears to be happening in your case is that the queries are changing the array in the background at the same time the user interface (table view / cells, etc.) is trying to update. If I tell you "peel each of these five potatoes" and dump them all out when you're still peeling the third potato, when you reach into the (now empty bin) for the fourth potato, it's not there, so (dumb potato-peeling computer program that you are), you don't know what to do and say "but there's no fourth potato" ("`potatoes[3]` is out of bounds"), or worse, you grab and peel air, or your own hand... Do you see my point?

My suggestion is to look at the example and any others you can find on the web for the use of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(...)` to see how others handle UI updating. Without looking into it much myself, I think the contents of your block should *only* handle adding things to the mutable array *on the main thread* and asking the table view to update. To that end, maybe once you're sure the query is complete, within the background block, "hop back to" the main queue to modify your `postsArray` and update the table like this:

```
// Inside the background block/closure, we've decided the query is complete,
// so we "hop to" the main thread to update our array and ask the UI to reflect it
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

    self.postsArray.appendContentsOf(objects!)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The idea here is that the UI will definitely be done updating from whatever perturbed it last time by the time the dispatched block/closure in our `dispatch_async()` call is executed. This little block of code is added to the main queue, which means it - and only it - will be executed during that "trip around the run loop". This ensures any changes to your posts array and subsequent UI updates will happen in *together* (as they should) and only *one at a time*.

You should apply this logic / approach to the other queries as well, since each is likely to cause the same problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean "another background queue" in the first question?

Comment: And could you explain more about the second one? How can I make my cell use of information from previous time ?   wow.. this is my first app, it takes  2 months to get here, this point is my desperate time.

Comment: What I understand is I should retrieve data once and update tableview(UI) with data that I retrieved, not to try retrieving data every time. And I gotta use dispatch_async() which will execute asynchronously and only once. So I need to put this when I retrieve data.  Is it right? anyway  thanks for the kind explanation, it helps me a lot, I learned so many thing from this post. I hope that someday I can help somebody like this. I will get there soon thank you again